# How to return Ajax response with no callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, callback, promise

I'm trying to find a solution to return data from ajax response with no possibility to **execute a given callback function**.

The following code is fix (third party api script) and the only thing i can control is the content of `myfunction`:

```
var myfunction( param ) {
   $.get( '/search', { q: param } );
   // no further ideas :D
   return; // <-- idealy the response of the ajax call
};

Promise.resolve()
   .then(
       function() {
           return myfunction( param );
       }
   ).then(
       function( res ) {
           return somefunction( res );
       }
   ).catch(
       function( res ) {
           return errorfunction( res );
       }
   );
```

The content of myfunction is by now a ajax call wich performs a database search.

Since I can't use a callback function I'm stuck there. I realy don't want to set the `async` option of $.ajax to false.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did u check there ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316697/jquery-return-data-after-ajax-call-success (second answer, with mutiple update)

Comment: Thank you @JaxTeller ;-) I got the solution by returning just the ajax call. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution. I only needed to return the ajax call.

```
var myfunction( param ) {
    return $.get( '/search', { q: param } );
};
```